# Error updating Monterey "An error occurred migrating user data during an install. Reinstall macOS" loop

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ssd, monterey

I'm having trouble updating Monterey for the last 2 updates. When I do it restarts in recovery saying:
"Your computer started up in Recovery because a failure occurred during installation. An error occurred migrating user data during an install. Reinstall macOS to resolve the issue".

Reinstall macOS does not solve the issue. The only way I found to fix the issue (update before this one) is by wiping my macOS partition clean and then reinstall the macOS. Unfortunately, because I have a third party SSD on my MBP, that would not work unless I replaced the SSD with an official Apple SSD, upgrade to the latest version, then swap it back with my third party SSD, do a clean install, and restore my backups. Needless to say, this is super painful and I'd really rather not do that.

Has anyone had the same problem? A quick search online yielded no solution :(

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that I've had this exact same issue for months now. I just restart the computer from the recovery mode menu and everything is fine (upgrade goes through just fine). I also notice that I used to have a directory of "Relocated Items" on every update (and it was always just my /etc/shells file), but have not had this happen since the issue started to occur. I've also been searching for a solution, but I haven't come across many people with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have [44 GB](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212551) of free space on your Macintosh HD before updating.

Comment: Yep, have plenty of space left. It's only with these 2 updates too, so not sure what's going on.